# How to get around this salesforce1 app cache issue

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have been working on salesforce lightning components and have succesfully integrated bootstrap, angularjs, etc. Till evening the two UIs i have, were matching perfectly. However just a minute later the UI in salesforce1 mobile app is cached somehow and not getting updated. I can still make changes and see them reflecting at url //myapp/myaap.app but the UI in salesforce1 mobile app is still the old one. I'm attaching both snapshot, i believe it's some app cache issue, please suggest me what did i miss.

salesforce1 UI snapshop => https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOWe9.png
regualar UI launched form developer console => https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Fwh.png

You would see the two UIs are different, in google chrome javascript console, i see some 'appchache no update required' message. I think it's somehow not updating, should i force it to update itself or something. Kindly help me on this.

Regards,
Sangram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got resolved, all scripts and stylesheets must be included in the component. Lightning component means you should always develop components, independenty. Just so to be included in the lightning app. I learned it the hard way. **implements="force:appHostable"**, is used to develop independent components.